# How do I create a screen which has several collection views one below the other?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

I want to create an ios app, using objectiveC, which has a scrollable screen which displays several collection views one below the other.
I am uploading a screenshot of a similar screen from a popular ecommerce app.

[image: Multiple collectionviews on the same screen using a scrollview or a table view]

I tried creating a tableview in such a way that all the rows are of 0 height but with custom headers. I am displaying different view controllers in different headers. I am able to parse the table properly but when I scroll down, it doesn't scroll smoothly.

Can you help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to create table view and inside TableViewCell create collection view

Comment: How would inserting the collection view in the table cell be different from inserting it in the table header? I mean what difference would it make? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can create a vertical flow collection view representing your each category, then for each collection view cell , return a horizontal flow layout collection view. This will do the trick.

Comment: But what if not all the collection views are of the same size and there are other elements too other than the collection views - like a table view and page view controller!

Comment: You will have to try this out, 
you can create a vertical flow collection view . Then in its datasource for each item , make conditions to get its position and return what kind of view you want as a UIcollectionView Cell. 
For size you  can do the same conditions and return the corresponding size.

Answer (score 0):

Use a collection view within a collection view. The outer collection view will have vertical scrolling, while the inner will have horizontal scrolling. This can be done with the `scrollDirection` property on the flow layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a scroll view and give the code like this...

```
 -(void)scrollView
    {
        NSLog(@"scrollView");
        for(int i=0;i<arrImages.count;i++)
        {
            CGRect frame;
            frame.origin.x=self.scrollViewTop.frame.size.width *i;
            frame.origin.y=0;
            frame.size=self.scrollViewTop.frame.size;
            scrollViewTop.scrollsToTop=NO;
            UIImageView *image=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
             [self.scrollViewTop addSubview:image];
            [scrollView addSubview:lblScrollView];
            UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
            [scrollViewTop addSubview:lbl];

        }
        self.scrollViewTop.contentSize=CGSizeMake(width, height);
    }
```

what ever you want inside the scroll view just add it as a sub view..